# Create a bat files based of a list of files

Tags: list, file, batch-file

I need to create a bat files based on a list of files.

Example of file list (the name of the files can be change):

```
vpn_1.1.1.1_udp_11111.ovpn
vpn_2.2.2.2_tcp_22222.ovpn
vpn_3.3.3.3_udp_33333.ovpn
vpn_10.10.10.10_tcp_1010.ovpn
```

I need a bat that can create a complete code based on the list of files like:

```
start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect vpn_1.1.1.1_udp_11111.ovpn
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe

start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect vpn_2.2.2.2_tcp_22222.ovpn
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe

start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect vpn_3.3.3.3_udp_33333.ovpn
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe

start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect vpn_10.10.10.10_tcp_1010.ovpn
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe
```

After create the code I need to save the bat in a prefered path.

The number and the files name can be change (in this example I write 4 files but files can be more)

All solutions provided actually for me do not work (do not recognize path of the file), U continue to search a working solution to my batch files.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks for support

Best regards

Comment: Actually i generate the bat code via excel but it's very slow and complicated, I need a simple solution like a bat that can create instantly my code based on a text list of files. Can you help me please?

Comment: A `for /f` loop can do this very easily.

Comment: @SomethingDark Can you provide the complete code of bat please? i have more difficult because contains " too. Thanks for help

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but you can use `""` in a batch script to echo a single `"`.

Comment: I know so little bat code, i think that code is not hardest but i know very little bat code, I hope some user can help me please, thanks

Comment: @placidomaio Start by reading information on how to do it yourself.  http://commandwindows.com/batch.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (filesList.txt) do (
   echo start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect %%a
   echo ping -n 10 localhost ^>nul 2^>^&1
   echo taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe
   echo/
)) > "prefered\path\created.bat"
```

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comments*

I tested my program with the data you provided. This is **filesList.txt** file I used in my test:

```
vpn_1.1.1.1_udp_11111.ovpn
vpn_2.2.2.2_tcp_22222.ovpn
vpn_3.3.3.3_udp_33333.ovpn
vpn_10.10.10.10_tcp_1010.ovpn
```

And this is the **created.bat** file:

```
start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect vpn_1.1.1.1_udp_11111.ovpn
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe

start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect vpn_2.2.2.2_tcp_22222.ovpn
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe

start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect vpn_3.3.3.3_udp_33333.ovpn
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe

start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect vpn_10.10.10.10_tcp_1010.ovpn
ping -n 10 localhost >nul 2>&1
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe
```

The created .bat file contains *exactly the same code* you posted above as the requested output, so I don't understand what is your concern... `:(`

**IMPORTANT**: In order to have a common base, you must do the same thing I did, that is, copy the "Example of file list" above and paste it in a file named filesList.txt, copy my program in a .bat file and run it. Then, compare the created.bat file with the requested code you posted above. You must confirm that you completed this test in any further comment you may post...

Comment: I tried but do not work continue to add in the script full path  [--connect D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\data\list.txt] need to add the file name contained in the list NOT full path. my list of files path is "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\data\list.txt" Thanks for help

Comment: Your "Example of file list" posted in the question have NOT paths, just file names. If this is wrong, you must modify the question and add a note that indicate that "The specifications had changed". Do NOT post new requests nor important info in comments! PS - I already modified my solution with your _new_ request...

Comment: I tried but do not woks, always the same error do not add the configuration name (do not read the files name in the list), this is totally WRONG solution do not read the files name in the list. totally wrong do not show the result correct. Do not create in files this part "--connect vpn_1.1.1.1_udp_11111.ovpn"

Comment: JosefZ edited this code adding usebackq and solve the problem, now the bat works perfectly with the JosefZ correction. Thanks to Aacini too for a part of script. Thanks to all, now my script works. Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (textfilecontainingyourovpnfilenames) do (
 start /low /max "" "D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\OpenVPNPortable.exe" --connect %%a
 timeout /t 10 >nul
 taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe /IM openvpn-gui.exe /IM OpenVPNPortable.exe
)
```

That is, read each line from the textfile and then run the procedure.

Note that *timeout* will provide the 10-sec delay and `>nul` suppress `timeout`'s countdown prompts.

Comment: I tried your code bat there are 2 problem: 1) the code do not recognize correctly the files name saved in list, it recognize the entiere path (D:\Programmi Installati\Openvpn Portable\list.txt) and after --connect add the entiere path of files list with configuration files (and not the file name saved in list). 2) I prefer to save the complete code in a batch file saved in my pc in a prefered path to run it in a after times and do not run it automatically. Thanks for help me